# Why would layout_width="wrap_content" take up the entire width of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

With this xml:

```
<TableRow >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</TableRow>
```

I would expect "wrap_content" to only be as wide as necessary to display the text on the button, but the button monopolizes the entire width of the screen...?

Comment: We need to see what's outside your TableRow in your layout - that's probably your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the width specification in your xml is ignored. From the [docs for TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html):

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

P.S. Did you have a compelling reason to use absolute pixels? That's generally considered bad practice.

P.P.S. Double-posting my answer to go with the double-posting of your question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this question?

[Button width in Android TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575155/button-width-in-android-tablelayout)

The issue could be caused by using `android:stretchColumns="*"` in your `TableLayout`, but it is difficult to tell without the rest of your XML.

Answer (score 2):

Dont understand....
Cant see layout_width attribute,layout_height attribute for TableRow.no Elements can be without these attributes.

Comment: Apparently not really needed, as I got it working as shown below.

Comment: I had to add a textView "shim" and give both the Button and the TextView a layout_weight:

    <TableRow >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>