# Simple Layout Conundrum - Why is Rhode Island trying to be Texas? (why is EditText using the entire width)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've finally wrassled an Activity/Screen so that it is pretty much as I want it, but I've still got a stubborn EditText that needs to be the size of Rhode Island and insists on being Texas-sized. Here is the xml:

```
<TableRow >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMilesBeforeNotification"
        android:layout_width="100px" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Please don't double-post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369254/why-would-layout-width-wrap-content-take-up-the-entire-width-of-the-screen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the width specification in your xml is ignored. From the [docs for TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html):

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

P.S. Did you have a compelling reason to use absolute pixels? That's generally considered bad practice.