# Android two column Layout

Tags: android, listview, gridview, sidebar

I want to make a layout like the photo below and the separate column can be click
I survey listView two columns, but there is no separate line and there is only one column click
How about GridView!? GridView can do like this!?
please help me, i have no ideal about how to do this, thx.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use TableLayout to achieve your goal. You will put 2 buttons in one row (then you get 2 columns). You should also set weight on buttons to 1 to attain two equal columns.

Here you have helpful links:

1. [Button width in Android TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575155/button-width-in-android-tablelayout)
2. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/
3. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html
4. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/